# ffmpeg video stream output multiply when I modify viedo in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I try to implement a proof of concept program which: (1)get video from webcam, (2)do some operations on it, (3)stream modified video on a web page.

I do it as follows:

1) In open CV: open webcam stream and output frames as a rawvideo, capture.py looks:

```
  import cv2
  import sys

  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if(ret):
      sys.stdout.write(frame.tostring())
    else:
      break
```

2) Run ffmpeg server by execute: `python2 capture.py | ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 640x480 -i - -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -s 640x480 -b:v 2500k -bf 0 http://localhost:8081/supersecret`

3) Run Websocket relay and http-server according to the instruction on page: https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg, in order to stream video in a browser.

I get the stream in browser, but when I apply any change(e.g. `frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`) on the frame inside capture.py file I get 9 small stream instead of one.[image]

The same situation occurs when I change video resolution while starting ffmpeg server. When I stream directly from /dev/video0 insted of pipe I get the proper stream.

How can I do some operations on the video and get the single image stream?

Comment: When you convert from `BGR` to `Gray`, you go from 24 bits / pixel to 8 bits / pixel. Maybe adding `-pixel_format pal8 ` for the output stream could do the trick?

Comment: @Catree , I added -pixel_format pal8 to output but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think it should be just an issue about how ffmpeg should interpret the size of the image buffer. If you do: `frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` followed by `frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`, do you still have the issue? Also, I don't know about `ffmpeg` and piping: what the command line is doing? Just redirect the OpenCV `frame` to the server or capture a stream, send it to OpenCV and then get the `frame` from OpenCV and send it to the server? If `ffmpeg` is just used to send to the server, did you try to replace `bgr24` by `pal8`?

Comment: I tried to add an extra line that you mentioned but it doesn't solve the issue.
Command line capture the stream (in OpenCV), then change the frame, then print raw video data which are captured by FFmpeg server. Then the server sends it via WebSocket to http-server and then javascript video player plays the video. I swapped bgr24 with pal8 but I get an error: "Palette size 32767 is wrong".